# Programmatic way to tell if your visual form is being previewed

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

We use the NetBeans GUI builder to create our visual forms.

We try to make them JavaBean compliant so that we can just drag and drop components onto the screen.
However sometimes this becomes difficult as the component needs to connect to a service that is not available to NetBeans at preview/design time and thus throws an exception and stops you from dragging and dropping the component onto the form.

As a work around I've added try catches around the connections to the services that I know will fail when NetBeans tries to instantiate the form so that it can be previewed.

This feels rather hackish though, I would prefer it if there was a way to check if the component is in design mode and if that is the case then just not instatiate the objects that will throw exceptions.

Anybody got any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have too much logic built into your form classes. You should consider taking all of that code that connects to your services and bundle it into one or more classes, and then inject those classes into your form at runtime. Then, make sure that the code that calls that object doesn't throw null pointer exceptions if that object is unavailable, as it would be in preview.

Comment: All of that code is bundled into other classes, but it has to be instantiated at some point which is where the error occurs. Now if I had some way of telling that NetBeans was previewing my form I could not initialise the class that is causing the exception

Comment: That's good that they're in separate classes, but the difference is that the gui class should not do the instantiation. The code that creates the form should inject those helper classes into the form.